# Is it the best approach? Database modelling, 1-1 Relationship, foreign key as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I will explain my problem:
I have two types of users on my database:  Admin and community_user..
Both share several attributes (Name, phone, status...)
But admin has an VARCHAR(50) specific field called "Position" as a mandatory field
and user has a field called "Vinculation", also a VARCHAR(60) as an optional field.
Both are strings typed by the user who have full freedom to type whatever they want to.

[image: Conceitual Modelling]

Does this modelling make sense? Using primary key as foreign key?

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user),
    id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    phone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    user_status VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
    id_user INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user)
        REFERENCES User(id_user)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    position VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

/*Testing, you can ignore hehe*/

INSERT INTO User
    (phone, user_status) 
VALUES 
    ("+5581", "carpe diem" ),
    ("+5583", "carpe cryy"),
    ("+5590", "carpe uhuu");
    
INSERT INTO Manager
    (id_user, position) 
VALUES 
    (1,"Sales Manager" ),
    (2,"Accounting Manager"),
    (3,"Community Manager");
    
SELECT * FROM User RIGHT JOIN Manager ON User.id_user = Manager.id_user
```

Comment: There are six ways (afaik) of implementing table inheritance. All with benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: And yes, that model makes sense. It's called "Permissive Class Table Inheritance". It's *permissive* since this model does not prevent a parent to be specialized in **multiple** child tables.

Comment: @TheImpaler this way of implementing that I did is possible? I dont know if it is the best, probably not, but if it is not wrong, well... it's start hehehe

Comment: @TheImpaler do you know where I can read more about this six ways of implementing? Any sort of help would be very appreciated

Comment: The six ways I know of are called: Permissive Class Table Inheritance, Exclusive Class Table Inheritance, Single Table Inheritance (Fowler). Semistructured Single Table Inheritance. Concrete Table Inheritance (Fowler), and PostgreSQL Inheritance. Some of them should be easy to find online.